# Can someone explain JUnit Testing in terms of Test-Driven Development?

Tags: unit-testing, junit

I was given a homework assignment of a class with only method headers and signatures, no body.

One of the requirements was for me to use the Test-Driven Development process by writing Junit tests for each method.

According to my understanding of unit testing in terms of TDD, you want to first write tests that FAIL, then implement the code that PASS the test.

However, does that mean once you've create the test that fails, you DONT modify those tests again, but modify only the code to make the tests PASS?

I ask this because what happens if I write a test that results in a compile error?

For example, in the code, there is a constructor with 3 parameters with empty body, i.e. no initialization of variables.

I want to write a test for the constructor that contains different data types then in the parameters to make it fail. But that results in a compile error, SO when I implement the code and initialize the variables, the test will STILL fail because of incorrect data types.

In this situation how would JUnit testing work in terms of TDD?

thanks!

Comment: Please show the code, and the test you have in mind. I don't understand what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

I am a huge proponent of TDD, but I believe that writing a test that doesn't compile doesn't provide much value.

The way I do TDD is the following:

1. Define the method signature that is needed
2. Write a compiling test method that calls the method under test
3. Assert something about the functionality of the method under test

   1. this should fail since the method does not have any functionality
4. Run the test and verify it fails as expected
5. Implement the code to satisfy the validation
6. Run the test and verify it passes

Next you can add additional validation to the same test or write a new test either against the same method or the next method.

In unit testing you can verify more than one thing in a single test but you SHOULD NOT invoke the method under test more than once. ie. if the method under test executes 5 validatable actions, you can verify all those in the same test if you can do so without invoking the method more than once.

Answer (score 0):

The test should test the functionality of the code. E.g. that Calculater.sum(a,b) calculates the sum. It should not test the Java language (e.g. the constructor matches, a method exists, ...)